# Ubuntu 16.04 - Create a Spigot Server Service/Deamon

Tags: service, ubuntu-16.04

I have a little Minecraft server running on my server for my little brother.

I am using Screen to run it in the background but I would like to make a service/daemon of it so it does not stop any more. I have looked all around the internet trying to find a script that does this for me but I cannot find one.

My start-up script for the Minecraft server is:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -Xms512M -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot.jar nogui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good way (especially with Ubuntu-based OS's) is to have a script run that instantly starts the server if it happens to close down/stop.

Here's a nice little sh script I've put together:

```
while true;
do
echo "Starting server now!";

java -jar yourServerJar.jar;

echo "Server restarting in 5 seconds! Press control+c to stop!";
sleep 5;
done;
```

What this script does is create an infinite loop, in which the Server instance is started (java -jar yourServerJar.jar) and restarts your server after 5 seconds of downtime.

**Save the above code** as **start.sh**, then type in your command prompt something along the lines of:

```
sudo sh start.sh
```

This will run the start.sh script file. (**Make sure to change the .jar to your servers .jar file!**)

Comment: Okay, well it does seem to work it's still in a Screen. I would still like to see it with a service. I will wait for an other answer, if I don't get any better ones I will mark this one as the answer.